# Compile error when trying to access a getter function in Veux 4 store of Quasar V2 beta app

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex, quasar-framework, vuex4

Compile error when trying to access a getter function in Veux 4 store of Quasar V2 beta app.

Unsafe member access ['item/getRandomNumber'] on an any value.eslint@typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-member-access

Error not going even after disabling it.
Please explain the cause the error and how to sort it out.

```
setup() {
  return { randomNumber: computed(() => store.getters['item/getRandomNumber']) }
},
```

getter.ts under module item

```
import { GetterTree } from 'vuex';
import { StateInterface } from '../index';
import { ItemStateInterface } from './state';

const getters: GetterTree<ItemStateInterface, StateInterface> = {
  getRandomNumber ( /* context */) {
      return 20;
  }
};
export default getters;
```

index.ts under module item

```
import { Module } from 'vuex';
import { StateInterface } from '../index';
import state, { ItemStateInterface } from './state';
import actions from './actions';
import getters from './getters';
import mutations from './mutations';

const itemModule: Module<ItemStateInterface, StateInterface> = {
  namespaced: true,
  actions,
  getters,
  mutations,
  state
};
export default itemModule;
```

store/index.ts

```
import { store } from 'quasar/wrappers'
import { InjectionKey } from 'vue'
import {
  createStore,
  Store as VuexStore,
  useStore as vuexUseStore,
} from 'vuex'

import item from './module-item'
import { ItemStateInterface } from './module-item/state';

export interface StateInterface {
  item : ItemStateInterface
}
declare module '@vue/runtime-core' {
  interface ComponentCustomProperties {
    $store: VuexStore<StateInterface>
  }
}

export const storeKey: InjectionKey<VuexStore<StateInterface>> = Symbol('vuex-key')

export default store(function (/* { ssrContext } */) {
  const Store = createStore<StateInterface>({
    modules: {
      item
    },

    // enable strict mode (adds overhead!)
    // for dev mode and --debug builds only
    strict: !!process.env.DEBUGGING
  })

  return Store;
})

export function useStore() {
  return vuexUseStore(storeKey)
}
```